# Explicit solution(s) for equations of the form $c=x^{ab}(d+ex^{-a})$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, transcendental-equations

Is it possible to find a solution in $x$ for equations of the form $c=x^{ab}(d+ex^{-a})$?

Of course, if we look for real solutions, the answer will depends on the values of a,b,c,d and e. But is there any general ideas, or theory about solving these equations?

Comment: Why not begin by replacing $x^a$ with $y$?

Comment: This could be done, we would then try to solve $c=y^b(d+ey^{-1})$. I think the problems we encounter are the same in both cases.

Comment: Are you asking if there is always a solution to that equation? Because generally, no that is not guaranteed. Just take $a = d = e = 1$, $c = -1$ and $b = 2$. Then the equation becomes $x^2 + x + 1 = 0$, which has no real solutions

Comment: @infinitylord What I am asking is a bit more. In my case, there is a solution found numerically, but this is boring. Ideally, I want to express this solution in terms of the parameters a,b,c,d,e. Also, the parameters a,b are some positive real numbers.

Comment: This is a [trinomial equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249060/series-solution-of-the-trinomial-equation) with a series solution.